# Sencha is not recognized as internal or external command

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

When I write `sencha` in CMD I get this errror:

> 'sencha' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

It is setup automatically like this as an enviromental variable:

[image]

but still it is not working.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you need to setup sencha cmd to your PATH variable, try something like this:
[image: Add SENCHA CMD variable to PATH variable]

Another option, is append to PATH variable in CMD session, like this:

```
C:\Users\myUser>set SENCHA_CMD_6=C:\mySenchaPath\cmd\6.5.2.15

C:\Users\myUser>
C:\Users\myUser>set PATH=%SENCHA_CMD6%;%PATH%

C:\Users\myUser>
C:\Users\myUser>sencha
Sencha Cmd v6.5.2.15
```

PS: I think you can set the variable to `C:\mySenchaPath\cmd` (without specifying the version), usually it contains a `sencha.exe` file that points to the current version.

Comment: Tried with CMD session and it is not working.Btw it works when I navigate to sencha.exe file.

Comment: @harunB10 Can you show me result of `echo %SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0%` in you cmd? Additionally, try running `%SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0%\sencha.exe` and tell me what happens

Comment: It is `C:\Users\hb\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.5.3.6`. When I run `%SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0%\sencha.exe`, it works.

Comment: Try run `set PATH=%SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0%;%PATH%` and then `sencha`, tell me the result

Comment: Nice, you're welcome! :) But remember this solution will only works during your session, when opening a new cmd instance you'll need to type these commands again. I recommend the first solution if you don't want to type this everytime. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had to do both, create an environment variable for SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0 with the path to sencha.exe on the C:\Users\user\bin path AND add an entry to the Path variable for %SENCHA_CMD_3_0_0%.